# Adding a new Item with _reference in ItemFileWriteStore

Tags: javascript, dojo

Now I can add items with `store.newItem()`. After adding it, it's placing it after the old JSON data.

But how do I place it in `children` (look at my code)?

```
{
    'id': 'WMD',
    'name': 'Web MD.',
    'type': 'continent',
    'children': [
        {
            '_reference': 'PUTTANONE'
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I add it into that place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have finished my problems. I get the idea from [this site](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2011-August/057544.html)

I'm still use `store.newItem` but have to keep the value that return, and use `store.save`

```
newValueTreeAdded = store.newItem({
    id: name + lastName,
    name: name + " " + lastName,
    type: 'fullName'
});

if(store.isDirty()){
    store.save({onComplete: saveStoreDone, onError: saveStoreFailed});
}
```

When its done, have a look on `function saveStoreDone`

```
function saveStoreDone(){
    store.fetch({ onComplete: onCompleteFetch });
}
```

And have a look on `function onCompleteFetch`

```
function onCompleteFetch(items, request){
    var selectDepartment = (radioWMDChoose)? 0 : 1; //select root node to add child
    var tempChild = store.getValues(items[selectDepartment],'children');
    var indexChild = tempChild.length;

    tempChild[indexChild] = newValueTreeAdded; //newValueTreeAdded is come from store.newItem
    store.setValues(items[selectDepartment], "children", tempChild);                            
}
```

Done! ***:D***